# Find a numeric pattern R

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I would like the find the pattern of either a 0/1 followed by a 2 which occurs more than three times in a row. I would like to find this pattern and transform the 2's in this pattern into 1s - such as

Input:

```
Y <- c(0,1,0,3,2,5,2,1,2,0,2,1,2,0,1,2,1,3,1,2,1)
```

Some Function findPattern that finds the pattern:

```
findPattern(Y)
```

And Outputs the following:

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I have tried the following:

```
as.numeric(Y == 2 & lead(Y) %in% 1:2)
```

Comment: Are you trying to find a `findPattern` function that will take in `Y` and output `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0`?

Comment: yes, i'll amend the question!

Comment: ok, so if you don't find the pattern, you'll return 0, and if you do find the pattern you'll return 1 wherever there was a 2 before and a 0 wherever there was a 0 or 1?

Comment: Does your vector only contain single digit numbers. i.e. from 0-9?

Comment: no, there could also be double digits, but always an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Find 0/1 followed by 2s

```
findPattern<-function(Y){
    as.numeric(Y==2 & (c(NA,Y[-length(Y)])==0 |c(NA,Y[-length(Y)])==1 ))
}
```

I add a NA a the start and remove last item so that you "shift" your vector by 1 position but still keep same vector length. This way you avoid `for` loops.

If you want to use `%in%` which avoids a second passage:

```
findPattern<-function(Y){
    as.numeric(Y==2 & (c(NA,Y[-length(Y)]) %in% c(0,1))
}
```

## 2. Select only those that have at least three 1s every other position

```
findPattern<-function(Y){

    w <- which(Y==2 & (c(NA,Y[-length(Y)]) %in% c(0,1)))
    centers<- w[((w - 2) %in% w) & ((w+2) %in% w)]
    result<-rep(0, times = length(Y))
    result[c(centers,centers-2,centers+2)]<-1
    return(result)
}
```

Testing:

```
findPattern(c(0,1,0,3,2,5,2,1,2,0,2,1,2,0,1,2,1,3,1,2,1))
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: With the extended 'Y' I have edited in the question the output of your answers give me:
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
not
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach to solve the problem where you can combine with the regular expression to find the pattern.

Starting vector:

```
> Y
 [1] 0 2 0 3 2 5 2 1 2 0 2 1 2 0 1
```

1) Find out all the `2`s preceded by `0` or `1`;

```
> ind <- as.integer(lag(Y %in% c(0, 1)) & (Y == 2) )
> ind
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

2) Paste the resulting vector into a string and use regular expression to find out the location and length of the required pattern, i.e., alternating `0` and `1` equal or more than three times;

```
> id <- gregexpr("(01){3,}", paste0(ind, collapse = ""))
> id
[[1]]
[1] 8
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 6
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

3) Extracting the location and length from the regular expression result and convert them into the index pattern;

```
> start <- as.numeric(id[[1]])
> end <- start + attr(id[[1]], "match.length") - 1
> indArray <- unlist(Map(`:`, start, end))
> indArray
[1]  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

4) Assign all the values at `01` pattern less than `3` times to 0

```
> ind[-indArray] <- 0
> ind
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Wrap them into a function:

```
library(dplyr)
findPattern <- function(Y) {
    ind <- as.integer(lag(Y %in% c(0, 1)) & (Y == 2) )
    id <- gregexpr("(01){3,}", paste0(ind, collapse = ""))
    start <- as.numeric(id[[1]])
    end <- start + attr(id[[1]], "match.length") - 1
    indArray <- unlist(Map(`:`, start, end))
    ind[-indArray] <- 0
    ind
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringi` package

```
Y <- c(0,1,0,3,2,5,2,1,2,0,2,1,2,0,1)
matchVec = stri_count(Y,fixed=2)
remapVec = as.integer(matchVec & (cumsum(matchVec)>=3))
remapVec
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: I just extended Y  so that if there aren't 3 consecutive 0/1, 2, 0/1 patterns found you still have 0.